# How to sum numbers in a range that only have a particular cell color [Excel]?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I would like to put a formula in Excel that would sum all the numbers of a specific range that have a specific cell background color.

Comment: Always consider how you can restructure your data before trying to fix the analysis process.  You are better off taking the information that you are encoding as a color and making it explicit in another column or something equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to return the exact color of a cell using built-in Excel functions, only if the cell is colored or not.

To do this you have to use a user defined function that can return the color of the cell, like [this example.](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/ReturnCellColor.htm)  Another useful link [is here](http://www.meadinkent.co.uk/excel-color-calcs.htm#Conditional) which indicates even these user defined functions might have problems if the cell is colored via conditional formatting.  Again, I recommend instead of coloring by hand or by conditional formatting to indicate some state, you make that state itself part of the data.

Perhaps a workaround is to consider what criteria you are using to apply formatting, and instead use that criteria for some sort of filter.

Comment: I was going to say this exact same thing, but then I saw rlb.usa demonstrate provably that you can indeed base a sort on the color of the cell.  Color me impressed!

Answer (score 1):

**You can select all of the cells and do a sum.** Here's how to select them:

[image: In Excel 2007]

Comment: The order of the cells cannot be changed, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Search the web for an Add-in called [xCELLcolor](http://fullscopesolutions.com/products.html). It exposes four helpful functions to Excel 2007-2013:  Sum by background color, count by background color, sum by font color, and count by font color.  No need for VBA or macros and no need to re-sort your data.

Comment: Note that this is a commercial solution provided by FullScope Solutions.